# javascript array | return an index if value contains a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings `stringsArr` and also I have a string `myString`. I would like to find first index of my array for which value is euqal `myString` OR contains `myString`.

I know method indexOf(), but unfortunatelly it works only if value equals `myString`. I googled through documentation, but didn't find anything suitable, so decided to ask here if I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and a custom predicate like:

```
stringsArr.findIndex(function (str) {
  return (str === myString || str.indexOf(myString) > -1);
});
```

If you're using an environment(/browser) that doesn't provide `findIndex`, the MDN page includes a nice short polyfill.

Comment: You've forgot to mention - es2015.

Comment: Nice solution, but still does not work for too many browsers :) Next project will write with babel, so will use it for sure

Comment: @Kania check the MDN page for a polyfill. You can add `findIndex` to all the current browsers and use it today.

Comment: Unfortunately in existing code adding polyfills is not an option :D looking forward for new project! Thanks for showing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` is probably what you want, but using indexOf on the String:

```
var tested = ['foot','bark', 'foo','cat'];
var match = 'foo';
for(var i = 0; i < tested.length; i++)
    if(tested[i].indexOf(match) > -1) console.log(i);
```

That will output 0 and 2.

To get the actual index:

```
var tested = ['foot','bark', 'foo','cat'];
var match = 'foo';
var index = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < tested.length; i++) {
    if(tested[i].indexOf(match) > -1) {
       index = i;
       break;
    }
} 

console.log(index); // 0, as "foot" includes "foo".
```

Comment: I'm looking for 'foobar' and 'foo', but indexOf returns ONLY 'foo'

Comment: nice, thank you, but my own solution I already have, question was about existing in JavaScript solution, like mentioned findIndex().